# Formatos de fecha en PowerBI

Tags: excel, date, formato, powerbi

estoy intentando cambiar el formato de fecha que tienen mis tablas y gráficas de PowerBI, originalmente me cargaba las fechas con formatos en excel `01/01/2000` como `lunes 1 de enero del 2000`.

He conseguido cambiarlo a `enero del 2000` gracias a los formatos de fecha que incluye PowerBI.

¿Como consigo que en vez de sacarme `enero del 2000` me saque `ene-2000`?

El código de fórmula es este:

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Segmento Cliente", type text}, {"Paquete", type text}, {"Fecha cosecha", type date}, {"Fecha proyectada", type date}, {"Valor", Int64.Type}})
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Acceder a la sección de datos (Data, sección izquierda)
- En la tabla que se quiera hacer el formateo, click derecho, crear
  nueva columna.
- En el campo de fórmula introducir lo siguiente:

```
    Nombre_Nueva_Columna = FORMAT('Nombre_Tabla'[Columna_a_Formatear]; "MMM - YYYY")
```

- A continuación se transformarán los datos de la columna al formato
  que has introducido.